# Where does an “ADD” instruction store the result?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, att

According to the description of https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html:

> Adds the first operand (destination operand) and the second operand (source operand) and stores the result in the destination operand.

However in my test, it seems different.

test  environment is:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS,
4.9.184-linuxkit
x86_64
gcc 7.5.0

source code:

```
int base = 12;
int add(int a, int b){
        int c = a+b;
        return c-33;
}
```

the result of `gcc -S` is:

```
...
add:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, -24(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    subl    $33, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Isn't this shows that the `addl` stores the result in the latter operand:%eax?And so does the "subl" instruction?

Comment: AT&T syntax uses the opposite order from Intel syntax (which Intel manuals use).  Use `-masm=intel` to get gcc to use that.  (It's the default on https://godbolt.org/)